# Why does onPressOut not trigger consistently when onPressIn works perfectly?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a component that is supposed to be a pressable icon using `TouchableOpacity`. I want to detect when it's held, so that I can show a view and trigger recording functions like a voice message recording.

`IconButton.js`:

```js
export default function IconButton(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      {...props}
      //onPress={props.disabled ? null : props.onPress}
      style={[
        props.disabled ? { opacity: .5 } : null,
        props.containerStyle,
        { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }
      ]}
    >
      <View>
        {props.icon}
        {props.children}
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
};
```

`Card.js`:

```js
const CardFooter = () => (
    <View style={styles.cardFooter}>
      <Text>{isRecording}</Text>
      <IconButton
        activeOpacity={1}
        onPressIn={() => {
          console.log("start record");
          setRecording(true);
        }}
        onPressOut={() => {
          console.log("end record");
          setRecording(false);
        }}
        icon={<MicIcon style={{ color: isRecording ? theme.colors.primary : theme.colors.text }} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

CardFooter is a function within another functional component.

Why does "onPressOut" only trigger sometimes, like on second, third or really fast clicks? The other function, onPressIn, works perfectly. I can tell it's not just the state that's not being set, the console.log doesn't show either.

Comment: It seems that it works if I remove the state function, just the console.logs alone are working.